# Send PDF File Stream always stuck in ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-8, pdfsharpcore

I only want to generate `.PDF` and send it to consumer, I using ASP.NET Core 8 and docker linux, for PDF generator, I use PdfSharpCore.

This is my code:

```cs
[HttpGet("generatepdf")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GeneratePdf()
{
    // Membuat dokumen PDF baru
    var document = new PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfDocument();
    var page = document.AddPage();
    var graphics = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page);
    var font = new XFont("Arial", 20, XFontStyleEx.Regular);

    // Menambahkan teks ke PDF
    graphics.DrawString("Hello, World!", font, XBrushes.Black, new XRect(0, 0, page.Width, page.Height), XStringFormats.Center);

    // Menyimpan PDF ke MemoryStream
    var stream = new MemoryStream();
    document.Save(stream, false);

    // Mengatur posisi stream ke awal
    stream.Position = 0;

    // Mengembalikan file PDF sebagai response dengan MIME type application/pdf
    return File(stream, "application/pdf", "GeneratedPdf.pdf");
}
```

I tried debug it using docker linux, and this happen

[image: everlasting loading]

I already try breakpoint, and code always executes

```
return File(stream ...)
```

but I always get stuck with infinite loading.

If I use standard debug or `dotnet run`, it runs well.

Why does this happen and how to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: could you try adding exception handling code which can help to get the actual issue. apart from that try using some other font. what is your docker container configuration looks like? you could try running the command `docker logs [container_id]` to get the logs.